# Is there a FormView (as in WebForms) equivalent in WebMatrix2?

Tags: webmatrix

Is there a `FormView` (as in `WebForms`) equivalent in `WebMatrix2` ?

Alternately, any suggestions to achieve Form-based `CRUD` in `jQueryMobile` using `WebMatrix`?

Any example or Tutorial?

Thanks.
Ratna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no built-in support for doing FormView-like CRUD in Web Pages with Razor, but there are several tutorials on how to do it:

Here's a full tutorial using the Web Pages Grid helper and a jQuery dialog: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/155/WebMatrix-And-jQuery-Forms